# How to find a String between two delimiters in Java?

Tags: java

```
String str = ":One;Two:Three;Four:Five;Six:Seven;"
```

How to get

```
str[1]="One"
str[2]="Three"
str[3]="Five"
str[4]="Seven"
```

Comment: With a custom function, what have you tried making it work.

Comment: See below - no need for a custom function.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
String [] tokens = str.replaceAll(";\\w*:?",":").split(":");
```

The first part removes the words you don't need (Two, Four...) the second part splits the rest. Note that the first item in the result (`tokes[0]`] is empty as per your specification.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = ":One;Two:Three;Four:Five;Six:Seven;";
    String [] tokens = str.replaceAll(";\\w*:?",":").split(":");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("token[" + i + "] = " + tokens[i]);
    }
}
```

prints

```
token[0] = 
token[1] = One
token[2] = Three
token[3] = Five
token[4] = Seven
```

Comment: nm, I reread the Q ... ::doh::

Comment: You can also try to replace this way to get rid of first empty string `replaceAll("^:|;$|;\\w*(?=:)", "")`

Answer (score 4):

hope this will help you

```
    String str = ":One;Two:Three;Four:Five;Six:Seven;"
    str=str.replace(":",",");
    str=str.replace(";",",");

    String [] tokens = str.split(",");

    token[1]="one";
     token[3]="three";
     token[5]="five";
     token[7]="seven";
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is:

```
str1=str.split(":");
```

and after that, for each member of the array str1:

```
str1[x].split(";");
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct a regular expression of the form

```
first|second|third
```

then use String's split() method to split the text by any of the delimiters.

so use

```
String [] tokens = str.split(":|;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it into an array using

```
str.split(";");
```

Like this:

```
String str = ":One;Two:Three;Four:Five;Six:Seven;";
String[] foo = str.split(";");
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question - the OP is using 2 different delimiters.

Comment: Ah sorry, I've overlooked that. I'll edit it..

Answer (score -1):

You can not get exactly what you want.

`str` is defined as `string` and you want it to be an `array`.

You need to use another variable to get results. Use `str.split(":|;")` function and store result in `String[] result`

```
String[] result = str.split(":|;");
```

Comment: Actually - reread the OP's Q. I just did and get it now ::doh::